# Is it possible to make sure addClass() is rendered before showing confirm() box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, confirm

In the following code, the confirm box shows before addClass has been rendered (i.e. Safari 6.0.5).  Is it possible to make sure addClass() is rendered before showing confirm() box?

```
<style type="text/css">
.preview    { background-color: #eee;width:100;height:100;color:red; }
.preview_s  { border:3px solid blue;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(i) 
{
    $("#testdiv"+i).addClass('preview_s');
    if (confirm('border not blue and checkmark not visible on some browsers until after choice is made'))
    {
        // Do confirmed thing here
    } else {
        // Abort
    }
}
</script>

<form id="testform">
<div class="preview" id="testdiv1">test1</div>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="test(1);">
<div class="preview" id="testdiv2">test2</div>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="test(2);">
</form>
```

Comment: Adding a class is not async, so it will be added before the next line of code is executed, as for rendered I'm not sure what you mean ?

Comment: Try putting the `confirm` in a short `setTimeout`

Comment: I suggest providing a JSFiddle please

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Here you go: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BvMFs/1/)

Comment: @Basic I can't reproduce the issue, but it seems like this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/aenJ7/

Comment: Perhaps the problem isn't so much my javascript as it is Safari 6.0.5.  Still wish we could come up with a workaround for that browser though.

Comment: In the interest of debugging can you hard-code `.css({})` instead of `addClass()` to see if Safari will recognize it before the confirmation box?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus it does appear that `.css({})` get's recognized before the confirmation box!

Comment: @Basic I wonder what happens if you do `.hide()` instead. Would the css of `display:none;` get properly implemented or would it suffer the same fate as `.addclass()`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `.hide()` suffers the same fate as `.addclass()`.  Furthermore, it appears that `.css({})` success depends on the complexity of the page.  I tried `.css({})` on a more complex page and it failed as well.

Comment: Very interesting. Have you attempted the `setTimeout` suggestion?

Comment: I wonder if jQuery is just too slow in this instance. Maybe you need native JS `document.getElementById('testdiv'+i+'').className += " preview_s";`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus native JS also doesn't work either.

Comment: @Basic I am all out of ideas. This is a Safari browser issue so you can either wait for an update to be released and test again or report this to Apple. Good luck!

Comment: I lied, you could also try adding jQuery UI and use `dialog()` to create a confirmation box

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not have a Mac with Safari but would something like this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(i) 
{
    $("#testdiv"+i).addClass('preview_s');

    // wait 20 milliseconds before launching confirmation box
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (confirm('border not blue and checkmark not visible on some browsers until after choice is made')) {
            // Do confirmed thing here
        } else {
            // Abort
        }
    }, 20);

}
</script>
```

It almost sounds like the DOM isn't able to fire fast enough after getting the instructions to add the class.

You could always increase the `setTimeout` by small increments to see how long it takes for the `addClass` to go through

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but: How would I pass my `i` variable through?  `setTimeout(function(i){` doesn't work.

Comment: If I understand JS variable scope correctly then it should simply be accessible as long as you don't change it before the `setTimeout()` fires off. Imagine running a `for` loop with an incrementing `i`. The `i` could change before 20 milliseconds pass.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to provide an ... out of the box methodology.

```
function runConfirm($div){
    if($div.hasClass('preview_s')){
        if (confirm('border not blue and checkmark not visible on some browsers until after choice is made')) {
            // Do confirmed thing here
        } else {
            // Abort
        }
    } else {
        runConfirm($div);
    }
}

function test(i) {
    var $div = $("#testdiv"+i);        

    $div.addClass('preview_s');
    runConfirm($div);
}
```

This should give you what you want because the function called will recursively call itself until the `.hasClass()` is satisfied.

Since you provide a jsFiddle, [updated it with this answer](http://jsfiddle.net/BvMFs/2/).

Comment: Interesting, but performs the same way as my original post in Safari 6.0.5.  confirm dialog pops up before addclass has had a chance to render.

Comment: alright, i edited my answer to try something a bit more creative. also updated the jsfiddle, appears to work as you describe.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but still doesn't work as expected in Safari 6.0.5

Comment: This is a browser issue then. You have a class applied to the element (it wouldn't fire unless the class existed), and yet the browser is not displaying the CSS of the class. Any solution you find will be incredibly hacky, if even possible, because to most browsers there is no difference between CSS applied by class and CSS that is visible on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I realized it in the following way, but I did not use it. Because it is ambiguous whether the class attribute is attached before the confirm box opens, and I disliked waiting for 80 ms.

```
const wrapper = button.closest('.js-item-row')
let needsSubmit = false
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(!needsSubmit) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const message = button.getAttribute('data-confirm-message')
    wrapper.classList.add('dynamicScaffold-destorying')
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(!confirm(message)){
        wrapper.classList.remove("dynamicScaffold-destorying");
      } else {
        needsSubmit = true
        button.click()
      }
    }, 80)
  }
})
```